# Remove object names from array of objects in js

Tags: javascript, json

I have data in a .json file, in the form:

```js
{
   "ObjectA": {},
   "ObjectB": {},
   "ObjectC": {}
}
```

I want to remove the names (ObjectA, B etc.) so I end up with 'anonymous' objects:

```js
{
    {},
    {},
    {}
}
```

`Delete` only deletes properties of an object, so that won't work. What will do the trick?

Comment: you can use array in json file

Comment: You can't do that with an object. But you could map to an array...

Comment: Why? Just use an array. Can't think of a real world use case for performing that operation

Comment: like 

    {
     "result" :[
     {},
     {}, 
     {}
    ]
}

Comment: This is not a valid JSON file. To be a JSON file, the keys would have to be quoted, as in `"ObjectA"`. Do you perhaps mean "JavaScript object" instead of "JSON file"? Furthermore, the result you say you want is not a valid object. In a JavaScript object, there are no "anonymous" properties; every property must be identified by a key. What were you planning to do with this "anonymized" object anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the cleanest method, but gets the job done.  (I added values so your console log is easier to see that the data is coming across.

```
var obj = {
   ObjectA: {fu:'bar'},
   ObjectB: {iheart:'pizza'},
   ObjectC: {something:'value'}
};
var obj2 = {};

var i = 0;
for (var key in obj) {
    obj2[i] = obj[key];
    i++;
}
obj = obj2; // don't really need this - could just use obj2
console.log(obj);
```

I'm sure this could be cleaned up and written in less code, but you get the idea of at least one way you can do that.

Comment: I nearly got it... now I have ```{ "1": {}, "2": {}, "3": {} }```. Am I implementing it wrong?

Comment: @IronWaffleMan - it just displays that way.  They can't just not have any key.

Comment: Righto, makes sense. I removed the labels with some regex so I'm good now, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, data can only be represent in one form i.e: Key->value. In every case, whether you talk about JSON data, MYSQL data or Object alloc in heap.

For making this easy we have generalised data storing in 2 methods.

1. Data in Dictionary
2. Data in Array

Dictionary holds each data with a unique "key". Like you already have in json "ObjectA" is a key. And Array also holds data with a unique key user don't have to specify that key while pushing data into array. we call that key "index".

So technically array is also a dictionary with auto-incremented "key" for each data.

Now, lets get into the point. You want to save your data in json with out any key. It means you have to save data in an ARRAY.

like:

```
{
   objects : { [{}, {}, {} ]}
}
```

but remember you need to save that array adjacent to any "key". You can't get rid from key->value rule.